# magento: category image for some are set as array and other as string

Tags: magento

I am having method:

```
public function saveCategory($observer)
{
    $event      = $observer->getEvent();
    $category   = $event->getCategory();
```

and from there I need to collect:

```
$category->getThumbnail()
```

but I am getting result Array!!??

I went and checked $category data and i noticed that I have thumbnail like this:

```
[thumbnail] => 157134.jpg
```

and this:

```
[thumbnail] => Array
            (
                [value] => 157134.jpg
            )
```

why like this? and how can I get my thumbnail?

EDIT

This is custom module and this is observer that is triggered on:
    catalog_category_save_commit_after

It is connected with admin part.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an academic question? You don't really care do you? You can just use `is_array($category->getThumbnail())` to test the type and act accordingly.

It is a hard question to answer on Stackoverflow because you are not running core Magento code, are you? I can't find a reference to catalog_category_save_commit_after. What version of Magento are you using?

But this is an interesting question. I think the type of the thumbnail may be determined by the way the thumbnail information is POSTed to the Magento controller and the way that the magic getters and setters work.

It is difficult for me to investigate because I don't have access to your third party module code.

What I can do is analyse Magento core 1.7.0.0 and if you capture the POST of the save category button in the Magento admin, the category image name in the form POST is

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="general[image][value]"
your-image.png
```

And if you add the special inspection code that I use for analysing adminHTML into the controllerAction:

```
file:app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php
class: Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController
function: saveAction()
```

add use this code below to expose the structure of the $data object

```
public function saveAction()
{
  //...
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

      //a hack to expose the $data object in the browser
      $this->_getSession()->addError( nl2br(print_r($data,true)) );
      //and normal code resumes...          

      $category->addData($data['general']);

  //...
}
```

and then we can see that Magento is passing the structure

```
//...
[image] => Array
(
[value] => your-image.png
)
//...
```

to the magic setter `addData()` and so actually your question might be why is it ever type `String`, we expect it might always be type `Array` because the POST input structure is

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="general[image][value]"
your-image.png
```

BUT I don't have your code. And your code is setting the key `[Thumbnail]`. To answer your question you should read the code of the controller that is POSTed to with the form value `[thumbnail]` then find where the `addData($data['general'])` equivalent code is and as above use the built in error message system to `print_r()` the data so you can see it.

The magic setter will set any data key with square brackets as an array. Maybe when you read the code it will become obvious why sometimes it is string and sometimes array.

I wonder if it is an array for a category that has a subcategory and a string for a category without a subcategory

Comment: sorry, more info part was for a guy who posted answer that was not relevant to a question and then after I added more info part he deleted his answer.

I do care about answer and I think that you might be right when you say that maybe is connected with category being subcategory.

Event catalog_category_save_commit_after is happening in admin section after you save category.

Comment: Can you work it out based on the information above? I you would like more analysis from me I will need to see the code for the saveAction() of your CategoryController. I'm using Magento 1.7.0.0 and my code does not reference 'Thumbnail', only 'image'